# Piping multiple commands together

Tags: terminal, pipe

Is piping multiple commands in a chain, one after another a thing? Like this:

```
crunch 14 14 1234@@@@@@@@aa | genpmk -f -d /home/kali -s Ourhouse | aircrack-ng -e Ourhouse -w - /home/kali/desktop-01.cap
```

Comment: It is a fundamental component of the Unix/Linux philosophy: connect a series of small, fast components together (without temporary files), using stdout->stdin. Programs used this way are generally called *filters*.

Comment: I understand that it pipes one command into another but I was wondering something like this.       Command1 -> Command2 -> Command3    Does this work or can you only use 2 commands

Comment: I have used at least ten commands in a single pipeline. Also, any of those commands could be a script or function that uses long pipelines internally too. The limit is either the number of processes your user can run at once (tens of thousands), or the total number of open file descriptors the kernel can hold (globally probably a million).

Comment: on a side note, pipe symbol is a line continuation in bash, so you can use a new line after pipe to improve readbility.

Comment: Yes. Everything is a thing.

Comment: @Archemar: `|` is not a line continuation character. One must escape the newline, thusly "`| \\`".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and is a regular thing.

The construction

```
command1 | command2
```

connects the standard output stream (`STDOUT`) of `command1` to the standard input stream (`STDIN`) of `command2`.

Note that both (or either of) `command1` and `command2` may be pipelines.